# Type with optional properties that cannot be explicitly undefined

Tags: typescript

I'm working on the following type definitions:

```js
type NumericKeys<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends number ? K : never
}[keyof T]

type Update<T extends Record<string, any>> = {
    $set?: {
        [K in keyof T]?: T[K]
    },
    $inc?: Partial<Pick<T, NumericKeys<T>>>
}
```

Things are pretty close to the way that I want them except that in the case of both `$set` and `$inc`, these types allow a user to provide an explicit undefined value to any of the nested properties. Ideally all the properties in both objects would be optional, but *if* the user provides them they must match the type of the corresponding property from the original object.

```js
type Item = {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    count: number
}

const example: Update<Item> = {
  $set: {
     // Ideally this would throw a type error because it should be type string
     name: undefined
  },
  $inc: {
     // Ideally this would throw a type error because it should be type number
     count: undefined
  } 
}
```

Comment: That example can probably be reduced to `type Foo = {a?: string}; const foo: Foo = {a: undefined}`, right?  You want to see that fail.  This is possible but only if you enable [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes) like [this](//tsplay.dev/WkGvLW).  Unfortunately that will affect your entire code base, so it might not be worth it to you.  Does that address your question? If so I can write up an answer; if not, let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: @jcalz Ahh yes it looks like exactOptionalPropertyTypes is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks as always! If you do want to convert this to an answer I'll happily mark this as resolved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't consistently distinguish *missing* from *present-but-`undefined`*, as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#13195](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195) and issues linked therein.  My general advice around this is that you probably shouldn't write code where something important hinges on such a distinction.

However, TypeScript 4.4 introduced [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes) which, when enabled, will not let you *write* `undefined` to an optional property unless that property explicitly includes `undefined`.  For example:

```
// --exactOptionalPropertyTypes is enabled
type Foo = { a?: string };
let foo: Foo;
foo = {} // okay
foo = { a: undefined } // error!
//  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'
foo = { a: "hello" } // okay
```

Note that you can still *read* `undefined`, since that's what you get if the property is missing:

```
const fooA = foo.a;
// const fooA: string | undefined
```

So if you enable `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` you can get the behavior you're looking for here.  But note that there's a lot of existing code that doesn't make this distinction, and if you have some of this code in your code base then you will start seeing errors there too.  This compiler option was intentionally not added to [the `--strict` suite of compiler features](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict) because of its potential for breaking a lot of real world code and harming productivity.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#44421](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44421#issuecomment-858870879) for a discussion on this; it was deemed "too invasive" to be bundled with `--strict`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/PTAEFpwUwDwQwMYBcDyAHJBLA9gOzgDYAKATtmlCUgJ4Aq1FAzqJs1PgEYFQAmAUHxoVQAMWzZQAXlABvUHAD8ALlCMkJTLgDmoAL4BuPtySgAZuJVjsh8xOkzdoEKGwBrONT62ps+SoCuuDxQppq8ek5glGQkAIR8zqD0wgDkgcGhuLwpLMy42CZwjIyYWpzcoEgSQlCgKWoa2ile4j5ycCoARAAWUAQE2J0Rzm4eAgh4ambiAII+tgB0cIbOE7hTtjMqDZo6AD6g6SFh-IIMtQBy-gC2lJgIANJQ1IwAPLQAfG18oL+gANoPFi4UCuZ7YUxJAC6KlogKhoFgSHYPDyNw4lFAClAQJUWQAbpQ+Lp-mDqBDoQIaqAAKpoHhwZHvREwZFBZgAJSgExIPFeO20ABp5LhqB8vvYfn8ACSMKBIZSyKV-P6A4Gg8GQ2hQxVwh5Q5V6QWG6WaBCKohwKiYQivIj3VzvYVXW4aR7PN6fcXEgRnYQASWR12+Kvwt226l2hhVwUYCA0GBwuAjjS00b+E0CSDx6KJunGkxMsDg1zQ3BUdIZTMDUGuEqVKtl8pUMkNKuc-uChAI1Eq3VYoAA7th-AQeH2yIP5JVzoiSDFQBiEHB-HKWCZGN0R2PF7VqQKtG2-mGoAEgscsvwVbpjY2zS2j78O13+r2kP3mMPR+P35Pp9TomwEhd2XVdakwDct2-XcZ2EXBcxIR9QEzXBs0Oc9Ml4Q183zIA)